# Undefined variable: "$font-weight-bolder" when running npm development server

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, npm, sass

In a vue project, that is worked on by a lot of people a recently started to get this error when running:

```
npm run dev
```

[error when starting development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwGGJ.png)

When running npm install, I also get this warning which might be related to the problem:

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I believe this is happening since I updated my node version, but I'm not sure.

From my research this problem might be related to node-sass or the css-loader.

**Details:**

- Windows 10 64bit
- node version: 12.16.3
- npm version: 6.14.4

**What I've already tried**

- Completely uninstall node and reinstall it
- Try different node versions with nvm (I always deleted node_modules and package.lock and ran npm install again)
- Completely delete my git repository and start fresh
- Delete node_modules and run "npm ci"
- install the css loader

Other development environments work fine so it's most likely something specific with this repository and my machine but I don't really know how to find the problem.
And also, the environment was working fine for me a couple of days ago so it's not a general problem in this repository.

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: well it just didn't work on my machine basically.
then i tried installing again on linux and it worked...
better don't use windows for node projects i guess...